# Refresh redis cache in apollo-server

Tags: javascript, redis, graphql, apollo-server

I am combining redis with apollo-server. I need a specific caching behavior: If the cache key is available in redis, first serve the response from the cache, then refresh the cached content by re-fetching the request.

my dependencies:

- "apollo-server-cache-redis": "1.0.0"
- "apollo-server": "^2.6.7"

I have begun experimenting with my server.js, I can intercept the cache `key` in redis. However, I need to implement the refresh function and I need help. I've been told that it's possible since I have access to the apollo-server instance.

```
const { RedisCache } = require('apollo-server-cache-redis');
import responseCachePlugin from 'apollo-server-plugin-response-cache';

const refresh = (key) => {
  const apolloServer = getServer();
  // implement the cache refresh by key.
};
class CustomRedis extends RedisCache {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
  }
  async get(key) {
    let supRes = await super.get(key)
    if (supRes != undefined) {
      this.refresh(key)
    }
    return supRes
  }
}


export const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  dataSources: () => ({
    postsApi: new postsApi()
  }),
  plugins: [responseCachePlugin()],
  cache: new CustomRedis({
    host: 'redis',
    port: 6379
  })
});
```

Comment: Did you solve it? If so, can you share?